EVA DTS for vending machine
I'm looking for information about EVA-DTS (DEXUCS/DDCMP) in order to get all of information in the vending machine (prices, stock, selles, etc) I contact with Eurpean vending association seeking information and that has help my to start with my proyect.
So, I'm developing a Java project using RXTX library and, per new, I can stablish "first handshake" but the next commands alwais commes with "error", i.e.
WHOAREYOU SENDED Receive : ACK: 0x5 0x1 0x40 0x1 0x0 0x1 0xb8 0x55

HEADER 0x81 0x4 0x40 0x1 0x1 0x1 0x6b 0x81

MSG 0x88 0xe0 0x0 0x1 0xeb 0x96

then:

0x88 represent an indication message

0xe0 represent the type frame

0x1  represent an error in security code or pass code...

EVA DTS COMMUNICATION

Baudrate has changed to: 115200

DDCMP PROTOCOL

Open successfully: true

START frame to send ASCII: @  \U

START frame to send HEX: 0x5 0x6 0x40 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x5c 0x55

Trying #0

Trying #1

Frame : @ �W HEX: 0x5 0x7 0x40 0x8 0x0 0x1 0xe0 0x57

STACK Matched,

START sucessfull

Send "who are you" frame

WHOAREYOU head frame to send ASCII: �@ B

WHOAREYOU head frame to send HEX: 0x81 0x10 0x40 0x0 0x1 0x1 0xa 0x42

WHOAREYOU data frame to send ASCII: w�      �   3  1

WHOAREYOU data frame to send HEX: 0x77 0xe0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x9 0x1 0x98 0x9 0x33 0x3 0x0 0x0 0xc 0x31 0x17

Trying #0

Frame : @ �U�@k��� �

HEX: 0x5 0x1 0x40 0x1 0x0 0x1 0xb8 0x55 0x81 0x4 0x40 0x1 0x1 0x1 0x6b 0x81 0x88 0xe0 0x0 0x1 0xeb 0x96

Response: Unknow error

Send ACK

ACK frame to send ASCII: @ �U

ACK frame to send HEX:

So, someone have experience with this protocol and can help me with documentation?
thanks you very much.
JC

As per EVA DTS 6.2.2 Enhanced DDCMP specification you have to send the security and the pass codes which seems to be zeros in your command message Who Are You.
Probably you have to look at the configuration of your device/machine and especially the security code. In my testing machine it's random 5 digits 57344 and pass code is left unchanged to 00000. After converting them to two bytes in big-endian it worked.
For example this is the command message Who Are You:
# 81 10 40 00 01 33 8b97 - DATA HEADER 
# 77e0 00 e000 0000 0309180e1d2500 3333 0b a105 - Who Are You, 57344 security code

# ACCEPTED RESPONSE
# 05 01 40 01 00 01 b855 - ACK
# 81 15 40 01 01 01 9782 - DATA HEADER        
# 88e0 01 e000 0000 4e45433030303030 00 08 00 00 00 00 4a64 - Who Are You response

And these is example of Who Are You with wrong security code:
# 81 10 40 00 01 33 8b97 - DATA HEADER 
# 77e0 00 dfff 0000 0309180f151b 3333 0b 196e - Who Are You with wrong security code

# REJECTED RESPONSE
# 05 01 40 01 00 01 b855 - ACK
# 81 15 40 01 01 01 9782 - DATA HEADER
# 88 e0 00 01 eb96 - Security or Pass Codes do not match

Bytes are grouped by data that represents. Hope that helps.
P.S. Your question helped me a lot to validate the CRC16 calculation.

Thanks for reply.
Yes, you right, the problem was the machine, the machine had pass code and security pass changed then I reset the machine and the problem was solved.
I so happy to help you with CRC16 calc :D
